# Custom dynamic error 404 page - guice / tomcat

Tags: tomcat, error-handling, tomcat7, guice-servlet, guice-3

I'm creating a web application using guice 3.0 on a tomcat 7 server.

I managed to use a static file to customize my error 404 page but now I need to customize the error 404 page using a servlet.

So, in my web.xml I add those lines:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

and in my module configuration

```
 serve("/error").with(ErrorServlet.class);
```

If I access directly the /error page from the browser it works.
But if I ask voluntarily for a non existing page,  I have a blank page. The browser has received the 404 status but there is no content. 
Furthermore, I have added log traces to the servlet and it appears that it is not even called.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I forgot that guice works as a filter so do not forget to add this line to your web.xml

```
<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which really helps me on the issue.

Comment: Just to make it even easier for other folks... Don't forget, that you have to also add <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>, so eventually you have something like 
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>